# postgresql subquery group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to preface this question with the fact that I am fairly new to sql, and I am in the stage of learning where I do not always know what questions to ask. So, please forgive me if I do not ask this question appropriately. I have tried searching for an answer, but I cannot seem to find anything that resolves the issue.

I am trying to run the following query that is intended to sum the column setdata.setvolume where setdata.dateoccurred > setcalculations.date. I am getting syntax errors on the group by clause. Any help is appreciated.

```
select
    sum(setdata.setvolume) from setdata
Left Join
    setcalculations
    on setdata.dateoccurred = setcalculations.dateoccurred
having
    setdata.dateoccurred >
        (select max(setcalculations.dateoccurred) 
         from setcalculations
         where setcalculations.pr = '1')
group by
    setdata.dateoccurred,
;
```

Comment: I think all that is wrong is the "," after group by setdata.dateoccurred

Comment: And your `HAVING` clause is actually a `WHERE`.

Comment: @dnoeth   the where is for subquery .. i thinks not after  the having

Comment: I'm betting that you don't actually want that `group by setdata.dateoccurred`. The sum appears to be sufficient.

Comment: @scaisEdge Not the `having` *before* the subquery ;)

Comment: I don't think it matters whether that condition is a `where` or `having`. Since `dateoccurred` isn't in the select list I'm wondering if OP actually wants the grouping though.

Comment: dnoeth was correct, and thank you very much for the help. Changing the having to where made the query run successfully. The "," in the select actually is an error, but I had tried to run it several times before without it being there; it was just left by mistake after many edits. Now all I have to do is figure out when it's appropriate to use where and having clauses.

Comment: `Having` is for filtering groups. Typically it will have aggregate conditions in it like `count(*) > 3` or `sum(qty) < 500`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error at the end (,)

```
select  sum(setdata.setvolume) 
from setdata
Left Join setcalculations
      on setdata.dateoccurred = setcalculations.dateoccurred
having setdata.dateoccurred > (select max(setcalculations.dateoccurred) 
                              from setcalculations
                              where setcalculations.pr = '1')
group by setdata.dateoccurred
;
```

but looking at your query could be you are looking for this

```
select  sum(setdata.setvolume) 
from setdata
Left Join setcalculations
      on setdata.dateoccurred = setcalculations.dateoccurred
where setdata.dateoccurred > (select max(setcalculations.dateoccurred) 
                              from setcalculations
                              where setcalculations.pr = '1')
```

Comment: Not sure I like the idea of a sin tax - might get very expensive in my case!

Comment: @JonathanWillcock   .. i don't understand  .. explain better  your comment please ..

Comment: Just a little joke.  I tried to edit your answer to syntax.  But you need to make at least 6 characters change, so it did  not allow me!

Comment: @JonathanWillcock   ... thank .. i haven't  see   ... anyway  if you have tried  to improve the anwer .. many thanks  ..sin tax ... thanks